# El programa trata de leer un arreglo y mostrarlo mediante funciones. Compila pero no se ejecuta satisfactoriamente

Tags: c

Estoy compilando con build essential en linux, lo primero que hago es leer el número de elementos del arreglo, después, leer un arreglo y regresar un apuntador y al final mostrar el arreglo.

```
 #include<stdio.h>

 int *leer(int);  
 int componentes(void); 
 void mostrar(int *, int); //Muestra el arreglo
 main()
 {
 int aux = componentes();
 mostrar(leer(aux), aux);
 return 0;
 }

 int *leer(int n)
 {
    int a[n];

    for(size_t i=0; i <= n-1; i++)
    {
        printf("\nIntroduzca la componente %d   ",i+1);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]); 
    }

    int *vect = &a[0];
    return vect;

 }
 int componentes()
 {
 int n;
    printf("Introduzca el número de componentes   ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    return n;
 }
 void mostrar(int *ap, int n)
 {
    for(size_t j=0; j <= n; j++)
    {
      printf("Componente:%d ", j+1);
      printf("%d\n", *(ap + j)); 
    }

 }
```

Comment: Por favor, agrega el código en la pregunta, no lo hagas a través de imágenes. Por cierto, el error se debe porque estás retornando un arreglo local en la función `leer`. Dado que al momento de terminar su ejecución, dicho arreglo se libera y por ende, el programa no tiene más acceso a dicho bloque de memoria.

Comment: vale, ¿cómo lo solucionarías? ya intenté declarar el arreglo como extern pero no me deja compilar

Comment: Podrías agregar el código en tu pregunta sin usar imágenes? Así te puedo ayudar mejor, de lo contrario, no podré probar tu código..

Comment: Listo, ya lo agregué, ojalá puedas ayudarme :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto que haces

```
int *leer( int n ) {
  int a[n];

  ...

  int *vect = &a[0];
  return vect;
 }
```

Es incorrecto. Tu variable `a` es *automática*, es decir, su tiempo de vida está limitado al tiempo durante el que se ejecuta el código de la función `leer( )`.

En cuanto que se sale de esa función, esa variable **y todo su contenido** *dejan de existir*; la CPU reutiliza el espacio ocupado para otras cosas, pero el puntero **sigue siendo válido**.

Es como si el puntero fuera una dirección, pero, al llegar allí, la vivienda estuviera ocupada por otra persona. La dirección es correcta, pero la persona que esperabas encontrar no. Pues lo mismo. El puntero es válido ... pero el contenido ha cambiado.

Hay varias posibles soluciones a esto; una de ellas es declarar esa variable en algún sitio de forma que se *prolongue su vida* durante el tiempo necesario. Por ejemplo, dentro de `main( )`:

```
main( ) {
  int aux = componentes( );

  int a[aux];

  ...

  return 0;
}
```

Pero claro, entonces es necesario modificar tu función `leer( )` para adecuarla:

```
int *leer( int *a, int n ) {
  for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    printf( "\nIntroduzca la componente %d   ", i + 1 );
    scanf( "%d", &a[i] ); 
  }

  return a;
}
```

Y tu función `main( )` quedaría así:

```
int main( void ) {
  int aux = componentes( );
  int a[aux];

  mostrar( leer( a, aux ), aux );
  return 0;
}
```

Y una última cosa: en tu función `mostrar( )`, la comparación deben ser `j < n`. Tal y como lo tienes, te muestra 1 elemento mas allá de los reales ... lo que es un *comportamiento indefinido* y puede causarte errores extraños y comportamientos impredecibles.

<sub>**Nota**: Deberías prestar mas atención a los avisos que te muestra tu compilador. No son errores ... pero indican código que te puede causar problemas.</sub>

Comment: Muchas gracias ya funcionó :)

Comment: @AlejandroJC La solución a tu problema concreto es lo de menos. Lo importante es que comprendas el como y el porqué de tu error.

Comment: Hola @AlejandroJC si una respuesta soluciona de forma satisfactoria tu problema considera aceptarla como respuesta correcta, así muestras a otros usuarios futuros con el mismo problema su utilidad y de paso agradeces al que te respondió su esfuerzo. Puedes mirarte [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/15089) para saber cómo hacerlo y su funcionamiento. Un saludo.

Comment: @AlejandroJC No uses los [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) en C, no es recomendable. Su reemplazo es: [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/).

Comment: gracias, ya lo estoy tomando en cuenta